# How do I combine two table with same structure but different information in one form?

Tags: ios

I have three separate databases for different branches of the company.  Now I require a front end which can access all of the databases depending on which service number is chosen.  For example, Branch A uses service numbers starting with 601, and Branch B uses service numbers beginning with 401.

These are auto incremented as services are added.  I would like some help in creating a form which prompts the user to specify which branch of the company the service is to be added to, and then sets the service number appropriately for that branch.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: grammar, spelling and clarity